# How can I install cpuminer?

Tags: software-installation, bitcoin

I am trying to install cpuminer according to this [tutorial](http://www.return1.at/bitcoin-miner-ubuntu/). The tutorial describes installing cpuminer using terminal.

> ```
> sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libncurses5-dev pkg-config automake yasm
>
> # clone cpuminer
> git clone https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer.git
>
> # compile
> cd cpuminer
> ./autogen.sh
> ./configure CFLAGS="-O3"
> make
>
> # choose a miner pool and register there
>
> # start the miner
> ./minerd --url=your.minerpool.org --user=username --pass=password
> ```

I have installed git and downloaded `cpuminer from git. but when tried to compile it I got this error:

```
user@user-Dell-Notebook-PC:~$ cd cpuminer
user@user-Dell-Notebook-PC:~/cpuminer$ ./autogen.sh
./autogen.sh: 8: ./autogen.sh: aclocal: not found
user@user-Dell-Notebook-PC:~/cpuminer$
```

I am new to Ubuntu and mining.

Comment: What do you get when you type `aclocal` on the terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are missing package `automake`. To install it open Ubuntu Software Centre and search for `automake`.

The clue comes from

```
./autogen.sh: aclocal: not found
```

The script `autoget.sh` (which is part of the miner) is trying to use the program `aclocal` which was not found.

To find out which file belongs to what package use these commands in a terminal window (once only):

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

Search for packages containing the program  `aclocal`:

```
apt-file search aclocal
```

Comment: @smurf hey thanks it worked but now its showing another problem when in tried to  login to mining pool its showing this error bash: ./minerd: No such file or directory . any idea how to solve this

Comment: this means that a bash script is trying to start program minerd from the current directory but there is no such program. Find out where the newly compiled minerd resides (command is 'find ~ -name minerd -type f`), change to that directory and try again.