# What is the lightest software miner for bitcoin mining?

Tags: software-recommendation, software-center, cpu-load, bitcoin

I have some hosted systems which most of the times don't have any work to do.
I wanted to run some software miner on them, but I read a Warning in this stackoverflow post : 
 [How to install bitcoin mining software in Ubuntu 14.04 for joining a mining pool?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468808/how-to-install-bitcoin-mining-software-in-ubuntu-14-04-for-joining-a-mining-pool) to not doing this.
does anyone know about a light software miner which is possible to configure it's cpu usage and something like this?

Thank you :)

Comment: FYI: CPU and GPU mining now are obsolete for Bitcoin mining and you will not succeed in making anything if you just try and put idle computers on it.  Note also many hosting companies PROHIBIT the use of crypto currency mining on their systems - it makes things unstable..

Comment: try asking this question at http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really is nothing to win with CPU mining anymore. See [In the ASIC-age, is it worth starting mining Bitcoin at home?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41276/5406)

Even with a lot of CPU power it is doubtful you'll ever reach a point where you could get a payout. Meanwhile you'll increase the power cost by a multitude of the gain.

Comment: This applies to GPU and FPGA as well.